# Al llamar función marca Message: Call to undefined function hola()

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hola buenas tardes tengo la siguiente función llamada hola($palabra) la cual lo único que hace es imprimir la palabra que le paso por parámetro pero tengo problemas a la hora de llamarla, realmente no sé por qué me está marcado el error si veo que mi código está bien.

```
public function index() 
    {//Dashboard
//aqui llamo a mi funcion
        hola('hola');

        if (!isset($this->session->userdata['sess_data']['id_usuario'])) {
            redirect(base_url() . 'login_controller');
        }
        try {
            $data['sess_data'] = array(
                'id_usuario' => $this->session->userdata['sess_data']['id_usuario'],
                'usu_nombre' => $this->session->userdata['sess_data']['usu_nombre'],
            );

            $data['menu_higher'] = $this->load->view('elementos/menu_higher_view.php', $data, true);
            $data['menu_left']   = $this->load->view('elementos/menu_left_view.php', '', true);

            if ($data['sess_data']['id_usuario'] != 1) {
//no es administrador
                $data['general'] = $this->reg_calls_model->empresa_general($data['sess_data']['id_usuario']);
                redirect('reg_calls_controller/empresa_calls/' . $data['general'][0]->id_general);
                // print_r($data['general'][0]->id_general);
                // print_r($data['sess_data']['id_usuario']);
            } else {
//administrador
                $data['general'] = $this->reg_calls_model->traer_general();
                $this->load->view("reg_calls_view.php", $data);
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
        } //./catch

    }

    public function hola($palabra)
    {
        # code...
        echo $palabra;
    }
```

> Error que me manda al llamar la función hola()

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si estás dentro de una clase, la llamada debe ser así: **`$this->hola('hola');`**

Comment: Hola @Javier para llamar la función **hola('hola');** dentro de una misma clase lo tienes que hacer con **$this** y te quedaría así **$this->hola('hola');**.  Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente por buena práctica, si estas dentro de una clase ya no es una función si no un método y para acceder usa el `$this`

```
$this->hola('hola');
```